# How to create Test Certificate in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio 2010. I need to add the Test Certificates in Signing tab.

But the "create test certificate" is button disabled.
What is the wrong? How to active it or how to create Test Certificate?

[image]

Comment: Is the code running? What type of project is it?

Comment: visual studio 2010 mvc 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Step by step, instructions for one that can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate
and essentially are:

`MakeCert /n publisherName /r /h 0 /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" /e 
expirationDate /sv MyKey.pvk MyKey.cer`

`Pvk2Pfx /pvk MyKey.pvk /pi pvkPassword /spc MyKey.cer /pfx MyKey.pfx [/po pfxPassword]`