# visual studio 2010 security tab missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want ti change the Security Settings in visual studio 2010 .
but in my project-> properties -> security tab missing.

[image]

Comment: There is no Security Settings tab.  What are you talking about?

Comment: Please see below :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900227/how-to-create-test-certificate-in-visual-studio-2010?noredirect=1#comment42353087_26900227

Comment: Signing is not Security

Comment: To enable ClickOnce security settings

    With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.

    Click the Security tab.

    Select the Enable ClickOnce Security Settings check box. - How to do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sfbfyk0.aspx#feedback

Answer (score 3):

I answered this here: 
[Why am i not seeing the security tab in my Office Solution properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496938/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-security-tab-in-my-office-solution-properties/39421819#39421819)

and here is my answer re-posted:

> I had the same issue and the solution was super annoying to figure
>   out. Someone on another website mentioned that the Security tab is
>   only relevant for certain types of ClickOnce applications so I started
>   playing around with various options and figured it out.
>
> 1. In the **Application** tab, for **Application Type**, select **Windows Forms Application** from the drop-down menu (other drop-down options might also work but haven't tried them)
> 2. Save everything: In the main menu bar of Visual Studio, click **File** > **Save All**.
> 3. Close your project Properties window (i.e. the one with the Application tab that we were just modifying)
> 4. Open your project Properties window again: in your **Solution Explorer**, select your project, go to the main menu bar, click
>      **Project**, click **Properties**.
> 5. Voila! It should be there. :)