# Why am i not seeing the security tab in my Office Solution properties?

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, setup-deployment

I recently published an office solution as a click once application on my one drive. My client downloaded it from there and when he tried to install, it gave him this error.

[image]

I want to republish it by making it a full trust application but i cannot find the security tab in project properties.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the solution was super annoying to figure out. Someone on another website mentioned that the Security tab is only relevant for certain types of ClickOnce applications so I started playing around with various options and figured it out.

1. In the **Application** tab, for **Application Type**, select **Windows Forms Application** from the drop-down menu (other drop-down options might also work but haven't tried them)
2. Save everything: In the main menu bar of Visual Studio, click **File** > **Save All**.
3. Close your project Properties window (i.e. the one with the Application tab that we were just modifying)
4. Open your project Properties window again: in your **Solution Explorer**, select your project, go to the main menu bar, click **Project**, click **Properties**.
5. Voila! It should be there. :)

Comment: Where to find the Application tab?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the files do not have [mark-of-the-web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/security/internet-macros-blocked) attribute set - go to the VSTO file properties in Windows Explorer and clear the web attribute.